# SELECT and GROUP BY multiple columns based on Max()

Tags: mysql, group-by, max

Current Table Events:

```
|  eventId  |  personId  |  type  | title   |  score  |
+-----------+------------+--------+---------+---------+
| 1         | 1          | movie  | Mission | 12      |
| 2         | 1          | movie  | UNCLE   | 32      |
| 3         | 1          | show   | U2      | 17      |
| 4         | 1          | show   | Leroy   | 13      |
| 5         | 2          | movie  | Holmes  | 19      |
| 6         | 2          | movie  | Compton | 14      |
| 7         | 2          | show   | Imagine | 22      |
| 8         | 2          | show   | Kane    | 22      |
```

MySQL Example:

```
SELECT @personId:=personId as personId,
(
  SELECT title FROM Events 
  WHERE rate = (SELECT MAX(score) FROM Events) 
  AND type = ‘movie’ AND personId=@personId
) as movie,
(
  SELECT title FROM Events 
  WHERE rate = (SELECT MAX(score) FROM Events) 
  AND type = ‘movie’ AND personId=@personId
) as show,
FROM Events
GROUP BY personId
ORDER BY personId;
```

Desired Output:

```
|  personId  |  movie   |  show   |
+------------+----------+---------+
| 1          | UNCLE    | U2      |
| 2          | Holmes   | Imagine |
```

The desired result is to show the MAX() score for movie and show per personId in the Events table.  My actual output contains NULLS and takes a very long time to load.  My actual Events table has around 20,000 entries.

UPDATE Solution (derived from first two answers to increase performance)

```
SELECT e.personId,
(
  SELECT o.title 
  FROM Events o
  LEFT JOIN Events b 
      ON o.personId = b.personId AND o.score < b.score
      AND o.type = b.type
  WHERE o.type = 'movie' AND o.personId=e.personId  LIMIT 1
) as best_movie ,
(
  SELECT o.title
  FROM Events o
  LEFT JOIN Events b 
      ON o.personId = b.personId AND o.score < b.score
      AND o.type = b.type
  WHERE o.type = 'show' AND o.personId=e.personId  LIMIT 1
) as best_show
FROM Events e
GROUP BY e.personId
ORDER BY e.personId
```

Comment: why show = `Imagine`  why not `Kane` ?

Comment: Because its eventId is higher.

Comment: eventId is lower for `Imagine` vs `Kane`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it is exactly what you need.

But just my guess, probably you don't need multiple columns?

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/04b27/4

```
SELECT e.* 
FROM `events` e
left join `events` e1
on e.type = e1.type
and e.score<e1.score
WHERE e1.eventId IS NULL
GROUP BY personId, type, score
```

**Update** If you need *the max score per person + type* you can

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/04b27/13

```
SELECT e.* 
FROM `events` e
left join `events` e1
on e.personId = e1.personId
and e.type = e1.type
and e.score<e1.score
WHERE e1.eventId IS NULL
GROUP BY personId,  score
```

Comment: That is a quick query but it only returns the the row with the highest score per person regardless of type.

Comment: Yes but the goal is to show the max score per person + type:                  SELECT e.* 
FROM `events` e
left join `events` e1
on e.type = e1.type
and e.score < e1.score
and e.personId = e1.personId
WHERE e1.score IS NULL
ORDER BY personId, type

Answer (score 0):

I made few modifications to your query.

Have a look:

```
SELECT @personId:=personId as personId,
(
  SELECT title FROM Events
  WHERE score = (SELECT MAX(score) FROM Events WHERE type = 'movie' 
  AND personId=@personId) 
  AND type = 'movie' AND personId=@personId  LIMIT 1
) as movie ,
(
  SELECT title FROM Events
  WHERE score = (SELECT MAX(score) FROM Events WHERE type = 'show' 
  AND personId=@personId) 
  AND type = 'show' AND personId=@personId  LIMIT 1
) as show1 
FROM Events
GROUP BY personId
ORDER BY personId
```

Comment: Thank you that pulls!  Although the performance is really slow on a larger data set.  But that might be expected.  Working on rewriting MAX() based upon Alex's answer.